# If $f(z)$ has an isolated singularity at $z=z_0$ and if $\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^{a}f(z)=M\neq0,\infty$, then $\alpha$ must be an integer.

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem : If $f(z)$ has an isolated singularity at $z=z_0$ and if $\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^{\alpha}f(z)=M\neq0,\infty$, then prove that $\alpha$ must be an integer.

This is Exercise 9.22.1 in Silverman's "Complex Variables with Applications".
Most of the exercises in this book are quite easy, but I have no idea with this question. How should I attempt?

P.S. There is no assumptions about $\alpha$, but I think it should be any complex constant.

P.P.S. When $\alpha$ is not an integer, even though I choose the principal branch of $(z-z_0)^{\alpha}$, does  $\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)^{\alpha}$ exist?

Comment: Did you try expanding $f(z)$ around $z_0$? Observe that if the limit is nonzero and finite, then $(z-z_0)^\alpha$ must get cancelled with one of the terms in the expansion.

Comment: Sorry I'm little bit confuse. Can you explain more in detail??

Comment: Will you please elaborate a bit more

Comment: In the Laurant series expansion of $f(z)$ around $z_0$, $f(z)$ is expressed as a sum of the powers of $(z-z_0)$. As the given limit exists, you can clearly replace $f(z)$ by its series expansion. If $\alpha$ is not an integer, then each of the limit $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}(z-z_0)^\alpha a_n (z-z_0)^n$ is either zero or $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a>0$. The hypothesis implies that $|f(z)| \to \infty $ as $z \to z_0$. This property is a characterization of poles. Hence $f$ has a pole at $z_0$. If the order of the pole is $n$ then $f(z) (z-z_0)^{n} $ tends to a finite non-zero limit. Can you now see that $\alpha =n$?.

If $a<0$ use a similar argument. Here $f$ has a zero of some finite order at $z_0$ and the argument is similar.

Comment: How about $z_0$ is a removable singularity or an essential singularity?

Comment: If the limit exists it cannot be an essential singularity.

Comment: $a=0$ is the only case where you have a removable singularity. Of course 0 is an integer! Essential singularity is impossible with the given hypothesis.